# Some windows in Window Maker don't have a title-bar

Tags: configuration, window-maker

In wmaker almost all windows have the typical wmaker title-bar, obviously (see picture).  Programs like Firefox or Thunderbird run in wmaker style.

But there are a couple of applications that insist on keeping their Gnome style title-bar though. For example, Nautilus or Spyder IDE. This last one cannot be resized. It's either full-screen, or minimized, no middle term is possible. I can live without Nautilus, and use thundar instead, but the IDE issue is annoying.

Is there a way of forcing them to comply with wmaker? It's not just about the looks of it, but also about comfortably working with them: making the window collapsible into its title-bar, or maximize to half-left side of the screen, etc.

Examples: nautilus, collapsed title-bar and not collapsed title-bar:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

They're gtk3 based applications. You can use [gtk3-nocsd](https://github.com/PCMan/gtk3-nocsd) as workaround.
[image]

[image]